# Which personal information should I publish on my website as a resume?

Tags: resume, websites, privacy, online-presence

I am planning to develop my own website as part of a (public) resume.

I am not sure about the information that I should share on this public space. I guess I'll include the same information which I entered on LinkedIn, etc. This would include a picture of myself and some of the jobs I had.

What do think about more detailed information about my studies, the projects I worked on and my relevant skills? What information are useful for recruiter but still protect my privacy?

I am working as a web developer, therefore the page itself could reflect my skills and my creativity. Should I include links to my profiles on SO, Github, bitbucket and such? I'll definitely include my LinkedIn profile.

Any experiences on this topic? Maybe someone working in HR? My best guess is to include a minimum of information (similar to my LinkedIn page if you're not logged it) and extend those if needed, since it's hard to delete things which are on the internet.

For clarification: This website will be a static one, like a printed resume but online.

Comment: General note: these are only useful if done really well, using technologies that you've used professionally and can talk about in an interview. I've seen one from a user here that was really well done (and which convinced me these can be a positive) and I've seen a lot that are terrible. Even if done well, keep in mind that not every manager will look at them and many won't care much for it. Your energy is still better spent on ensuring that you submit a well-written, customised resume and a thoughtful cover letter.

Comment: Be prepared for every scammer, junk mailer, robo caller etc under the sun to scrape your information and start contacting you 24/7

Answer (score 1):

As a way be noticed by another method of searching for candidates it is fine. Just don't avoid the other methods: posting on job sites, LinkedIn,....

Keep in mind that you will still need to have the ability to submit that information as a PDF or other document, and you have to be able to enter that information onto the corporate website when you formally apply. In some of these cases the info has to be presented in a very flat unexciting way, make sure the conversion doesn't take a lot of effort.

The info that you must include is a mechanism for them to contact you. You must also have a contact system that will allow them to provide their contact info to you. Including your phone number would be a bad idea because it can be scraped and then the stream of calls unrelated to jobs would be annoying. If you give an email address it must be one that is permanent, but not vital to your life - that way all the spam and increased traffic can be easily dealt with.

> My best guess is to include a minimum of information (similar to my
>   LinkedIn page if you're not logged it) and extend those if needed,
>   since it's hard to delete things which are on the internet.

I would never log in just to read more details. My job as a recruiter is to get appropriate contacts. The info you are protecting might be very interesting; but I have zero interest in creating yet another username and password, just to find out if one person is eligible for further consideration.

Oh when I do contact you, I will be asking for a resume, and will give you a link to apply for jobs: all you will need is to create a username and password on the job application site...

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself **why** you are posting public information about yourself.  Are you:

1. Hoping for unsolicited job offers?
2. Creating a post to direct potential people that want to hire you?

I am a highly skilled and experienced professional that is in high demand.  Even then, I don't expect to get unsolicited job offers and certainly not because I developed a website or a LinkedIn site.

Anybody that I want to hire me won't be searching for me randomly on the web.  All the jobs I've gotten have been from personal referrals.

As a *'grey beard'*, I find no value in knowing your personal details when looking to **hire**.  I want to hear you talk to me personally about your strengths / weaknesses.  I want to talk to people you know or have worked with you about the same.

There is no room in that dialog for a posted resume with tidbits of personal information.  I maintain a small footprint on LinkedIn; enough to satisfy the curiosity of a few people.

Save the personal information for social media - that's what it is for, socializing.  Focus on your economic value for job searching.  Know what you are worth and why.  Seek out opportunities proactively.  Don't try to passively 'fish' for jobs by posting an attractive resume, that's sounds a little conceited.

Comment: Recruiters send unsolicited interview offers all the time upon seeing a LinkedIn profile. I thought that was one of the things LinkedIn was created for.